# Upgrade of tomcat from 9.0.64 to 10.0.22

Tags: spring, spring-boot, tomcat, servlets, tomcat10

what come in place of **MockHttpServletResponse** in servlet 5? This class is not supporting in servlet 5, what is alternative?

Answer (score 1):

Spring 5 is not compatible with Tomcat 10 due to the package renaming from javax to jakarta. The Spring that will work with jakarta package names will be Spring 6.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/25276

"This is to be expected. Tomcat 10 is an implementation of the Servlet 5 specification (part of Jakarta EE 9) that renamed all of the packages from javax.servlet to jakarta.servlet. Neither Spring Boot nor Spring Framework supports Jakarta EE 9 at this time. Support is planned, hopefully for Spring Framework 6 and Spring Boot 3, assuming the rest of the ecosystem is ready."

The alternative is to stay on Tomcat 9 until Spring 6 is out.